# Multiple DDL queries on a single table in a single transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, sql-server-ce, alter-table

Can I rely on SQL Server (and SQL Server Compact) to do multiple `ALTER TABLE` queries on a single table in one go, instead of applying changes sequentally, if all queries are within a single transaction?

I'm generating DML queries from the code and want to simplify code, but I'd prefer to avoid performance issues.

For example, is there difference, performance-wise, between this code:

```
  BEGIN TRAN
  ALTER TABLE t ADD COLUMN a int
  ALTER TABLE t ADD COLUMN b int
  ALTER TABLE t ADD COLUMN c int
  COMMIT TRAN
```

and this code:

```
  BEGIN TRAN
  ALTER TABLE t ADD COLUMN a int
              , ADD COLUMN b int
              , ADD COLUMN c int
  COMMIT TRAN
```

P.S. Information on other relational database engines would be useful too, just in case.

Answer (score 1):

They will be sequential within the transaction, all-or-nothing to other sessions outside the transaction. If you're concerned about performance, consider the fact that executing DDL statements on a table will lock the entire table for the duration of the transaction, so do not do this on live high-traffic tables.

Answer (score 1):

The second case is in principle preferable because it gives the opportunity for the optimizer to do its business. In particular, the data dictionary will most likely be read and written in one and all changes to the tablespace will also be done in one go. But I doubt just by adding ints, like in the example, it will make a big difference. And definitely engine-specific.